# SQL : Getting data as well as count from a single table for a month

Tags: sql, database, teradata, subquery

I am working on a SQL query where I have a rather huge data-set. I have the table data as mentioned below.

Existing table :

```
  +---------+----------+----------------------+
    | id(!PK)      | name     |      Date       |
    +---------+----------+----------------------+
    | 1       | abc      |         21.03.2015   |
    | 1       | def      |          22.04.2015  |
    | 1       | ajk      |          22.03.2015  |
    | 3       | ghi      |          23.03.2015  |
    +-------------------------------------------+
```

What I am looking for is an insert query into an empty table. The condition is like this :

```
Insert in an empty table where id is common, count of names common to an id for march.
```

Output for above table would be like

```
  +---------+----------+------------------------+
    | some_id      | count     |      Date      |
    +---------+----------+----------------------+
    | 1       | 2      |         21.03.2015     |
    | 3       | 1      |          23.03.2015    |
    +-------------------------------------------+
```

All I have is :

```
insert into empty_table values (some_id,count,date) 
select id,count(*),date from existing_table where id=1;
```

Unfortunately above basic query doesn't suit this complex requirement.

Any suggestions or ideas? Thank you.

Udpated query

```
insert into empty_table  
select id,count(*),min(date) 
from existing_table  where
          date >= '2015-03-01' and
          date < '2015-04-01'
group by id;
```

Comment: Tag the appropriate RDBMS involved.

Comment: @RahulTripathi : Tagged, thank you. But an SQL syntax will do as I can convert the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you want the number of unique names per id:

```
insert into empty_table  
select id
   ,count(distinct name)
   ,min(date) 
from existing_table 
where date >= DATE '2015-03-01'
  and date < DATE '2015-04-01'
group by id;
```

Comment: This looks correct... I will try on a small table which I am creating and will come back to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just need a date condition:

```
insert into empty_table(some_id, count, date) 
    select id, count(*), min(date)
    from existing_table
    where id = 1 and
          date >= date '2015-03-01' and
          date < date '2015-04-01'
    group by id;
```

Note: the list after the table name contains the columns being inserted.  There is no `values` keyword when using `insert . . . select`.

Comment: I don't want to specify conditon like id=1, as I am looking for count with common id's.

Comment: Can you please check the main post, I have put an updated query. Thank you

Comment: Then remove id =1 .. and make the group by id,min(date)

Comment: @Phoenician : And that puts the count in `count` properly? Unfortunately the data-set is too huge to run each query so I have to be sure, I hope you understand.

Comment: yes it will do the count properly .. you are just grouping the outpout result and not the count

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into empty_table  
select id, count(*) as mycnt, min(date) as mydate
from existing_table 
group by id, year_month(date);
```

Please use function provided by your RDBMS obtaining date part containing only year and month as far as you did not provide the RDBMS version and the date processing functionality varies wildly between them.

Comment: This seems wrong, there is no `mycnt` in existing_table, date can be compared directly in teradata as Gordon has done.

Comment: mycnt (or mydate) is just an alias, please feel free to replace, or leave out as needed. I used group for part of the date because I thought you want to process the whole table at once. If you can restrict the date by WHERE, it's the way to go.